# Vertices of 2 self-polar triangles lie on conic

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, projective-geometry, plane-geometry

I have conic $\gamma$ and two self-polar triangles $ABC$, $XYZ$ with respect to my conic. Why can I construct a one conic through $ABCXYZ$?

Answer (score 1):

The classic literature has synthetic proofs. Back in the day, self-polar triangles were referred to as *self-conjugate* triangles.

Examples are:

- [Hatton, *Projective Geometry*, Chapter XIX, pg 260](https://archive.org/details/cu31924060184045/page/n275/mode/2up)
- [Milne, *Cross Ratio Geometry*, Article 196, pg 189](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.90533/page/n213/mode/2up)
- [Russel, *Pure Geometry*, Chap XIV, pg 172](https://archive.org/details/dli.ernet.523171/page/171/mode/2up)

(These synthetic proofs may require some leafing backwards to pick up prerequisite material)

If you prefer an analytic proof, one is sketched in [Salmon, *Conic Sections*, pg. 341, Ex. 1](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.162705/page/n355/mode/2up).  Again, some leafing backwards may be required.

There is a proposed analytic proof on [math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2565048/vertices-of-two-triangles-self-polar-with-respect-to-one-conic-lie-on-another), but I have not vetted it.